# How to create an auto-refreshing table?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I created an html page where I load the csv file(where the data is already in a table) and it recreates the table and to update it I have to load the file every day.

How do I update this table automatically without me loading the file every day?

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial=1.0">
    <title>Pricelist</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.18.5/xlsx.full.min.js" integrity="sha512-r22gChDnGvBylk90+2e/ycr3RVrDi8DIOkIGNhJlKfuyQM4tIRAI062MaV8sfjQKYVGjOBaZBOA87z+IhZE9DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="table"></div>
<script>
    let table = document.querySelector(".table");
    (
        async()=>{
            let workbook = XLSX.read(await(await fetch("./excel/ProdottiEstero0707.xlsx")).arrayBuffer());
            console.log(workbook);
            let worksheet = workbook.SheetNames;
            worksheet.forEach(name=>{
                let html = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(workbook.Sheets[name]);
                table.innerHTML +=  `
                <img src="atomiclogo02.png" width=50 height=50/> &nbsp <h3 style="display: inline-block;">Pricelist 07/07/2023</h3><br>${html}`
            })
        }
    )()
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the table automatically without manually loading the file every day, you can use JavaScript to fetch the file periodically and update the table content. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial=1.0">
    <title>Pricelist</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.18.5/xlsx.full.min.js" integrity="sha512-r22gChDnGvBylk90+2e/ycr3RVrDi8DIOkIGNhJlKfuyQM4tIRAI062MaV8sfjQKYVGjOBaZBOA87z+IhZE9DA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="table"></div>
    <script>
        let table = document.querySelector(".table");

        async function updateTable() {
            let workbook = XLSX.read(
                await (await fetch("./excel/ProdottiEstero0707.xlsx")).arrayBuffer()
            );
            console.log(workbook);
            let worksheet = workbook.SheetNames;
            table.innerHTML = ""; // Clear the table before updating
            worksheet.forEach((name) => {
                let html = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(workbook.Sheets[name]);
                table.innerHTML += `
                    <img src="atomiclogo02.png" width=50 height=50/> &nbsp 
                    <h3 style="display: inline-block;">Pricelist 07/07/2023</h3><br>
                    ${html}`;
            });
        }

        // Update the table every day (adjust the interval as needed)
        setInterval(updateTable, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 24 hours

        // Initial update
        updateTable();
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

In this example, the updateTable function fetches the file, reads the workbook, and updates the table content. The setInterval function is used to call the updateTable function every 24 hours (adjust the interval as needed). Additionally, the table is initially updated immediately after the page loads.